# Can I adjust the baseline in an NSAttributedString without increasing the line height?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In the San Francisco font, brackets are a bit low if they surround numbers. An example from the app I'm making, using an `NSAttributedString`:

[image: example]

I'd like to increase the baseline for the brackets by a pixel or two, but when I do that using the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` attribute, the line height is increased by two pixels as well. The text is inside a `UITextView`, and I really wouldn't like the line height to change. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I'm wondering if you can set `maximumLineHeight` in `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, adding `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` to the parenthesis to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do it is to force the maximum line height with `NSParagraphAttributeName`.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setMaximumLineHeight:maxHeightWanted];

NSDictionary *parenthesisAttributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style, 
                                        NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:@(baselineWanted), 
                                        NSFontAttributeName:sameFontWithBiggerPointSize};
```

Comment: Objective-C, huh? Old-school ;)

Comment: @TimVermeulen Language wasn't specified. The code is not that hard to translate, and I prefer the square brackets :p

Comment: Haha, language indeed wasn't specified because it's not of any relevance :)