# Subscript and superscript Strings adding extra space between lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring, nsattributedstring

Adding subscript and superscript to attributed string, making gaps between the lines get bigger than usual. I want all the lines to be equally spaced.

I have attached a screenshot for reference, which can show line gap difference between the first two lines and next two lines because of the subscripts added.

Can u help one help me out in this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
if ([start isEqualToString:@"<subscript>"]) {


   [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:replacingRange withString:tempString];

   [attributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"-1" range:NSMakeRange(startRange.location, tempString.length)];
 }
 if ([start isEqualToString:@"<superscript>"]) {

   [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:replacingRange withString:tempString];

    NSInteger textheight = 1;
    CFNumberRef subscriptHeight = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberNSIntegerType, &textheight);

   [attributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:(__bridge id _Nonnull)(subscriptHeight) range:NSMakeRange(startRange.location, tempString.length)];

 }
```

Comment: Is that a statement or something you want to achieve? *Are* the line gaps increased or do you *want* them to be increased?

Comment: @luk2302 He is trying to keep them constant. It does change the lines height which they appear

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727921/can-i-adjust-the-baseline-in-an-nsattributedstring-without-increasing-the-line-h

Answer (score 0):

The RTF tag for this is "\noextrasprl".  I don't know if UITextView supports it but you could try assigning this as an attribute for the whole text (don't know if the attributes key will need the backslash or not)é